# How can I handle errors in Data sources in PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot

I've setup a report that pulls from multiple XML data sources off the web. These should return a table.

Occasionally, no data will exists in a report and the server returns:
[image]

Subsequently, my Table.Combine query fails:

```
An error occurred in the ‘Source3’ query. Expression.Error: The field 
'Table' of the record wasn't found.
```

My current merge query looks like:

```
let
  Source = Table.Combine({Source1, Source2, Source3, Source4})
in
  Source
```

How can I check in M/PowerQuery to see if the Data Source has returned a structure table, and include/exclude it from the combined query?

Comment: I typed this into a Google search window for you: "verify power query source contains table".  This was one of the results: Handling Data Source Errors In Power Query (https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/09/18/handling-data-source-errors-in-power-query/)  Have not tried it but you develop a sense for these things after a while and it passes the smell test.

Comment: Thanks @ProfoundlyOblivious, that indirectly helped me find the right answer.

Comment: Awesome. Glad it helped. If you update your question with the solution that worked for you then you will likely help other people with the same, or similar, problem.